# Jquery append string from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have array tags = ['str1', 'str2'];

And what i need is implement this tags to ul by this template -

```
<li><span>str1</span></li>
<li><span>str2</span></li>
```

At first i have only this tag:

```
<ul id="tags">

</ul>
```

How can i do it on jquery?

Edited : sry i'm modified question plz check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating the entire list content, try::

```
var tags = ['str1', 'str2'];
var lis = $.map(tags, function(element, index) {
    return $("<li />").append($("<span></span>").text(element));
});
$("#tags").append(lis);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/SYQpa/1/

Comment: i have already one li in ul, how can i implement new li before this first li ?

Comment: @TimurShahbanov Change `append` for `prepend`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
var i = 0;
var my_arr = ['str1','str2'];
$(my_arr).each(function(){
     $('#tags').append('<li><span>' + this + '</li></span>');
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dnwuj/1/)

Comment: See my edit as per your edit

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve this, however using a `documentFragment` will avoid multiple DOM reflows.

```
var $frag = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

$.each(tags, function (index, text) {
    $frag.append($('<li><span>' + text + '</span></li>'));
});

$('#tags').append($frag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tags = ['str1', 'str2'];

$(tags).each(function)({
 $("#tags").append('<li><span>str1</span></li><li><span>'+this+'</span></li>');
});
```